# ERROR [IM002] when trying to pull data from a csv file

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to import data from a csv file on my local machine into an SSRS report. I have used this connection string

[image: con string]

and when I try to execute the query in the query desigener window I get the required data.

[image: query]

but when I come to run the report I get the error that ssrs cannot connect to the datasource. When I hit test connection in the datasource properties window I get this error.

[image: error]

I don't understand why it would work in the query editor but not in the general report. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the error occur when you preview running on your local or is the report deployed remotely when you get an error?

Comment: it occurs when I hit run from the report builder so local I guess